# Hide the backoffice link OutSystem

Tags: outsystems

I'm trying to hide the backoffice link when the user doesn't have permission to access it.
This is the table I use.

[image: Database outsystem]

Comment: If you want to do it on the `TipeADm` column just put an if statement around it with an expression refering to the column. If you want to do it based on a role you can see an action to check for the role if you expand the role in service studio.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely use Roles for that one. And even filter the aggregate based on the user's permission.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use if widget:

[image: Usage of 'If Widget']

In the Logic tab just create a Client Action (for ex. `HasBackOfficePermission`) wich takes your table and returns a value from `TipeADm` column.

In the properties, mark this Client Action as a Function and use it in the IF condition, just add the following Expression:

```
HasBackOfficePermission()
```

Don't forget to specify the necessary input and output parameters for your client action.

[If Widget](https://success.outsystems.com/documentation/11/reference/outsystems_language/interfaces/designing_screens/if_widget/)